# Is there a way to customize the date range in Google Analytics and save that as my preference?

Tags: google-analytics

Whenever I open my Google Analytics account, it shows me a default date range (last one month). But I am not interested in this range and I always change it to display the last 3 days.

Just to highlight what date range I am referring to, here's a screenshot:

[image]

Is there a way to do this only once and save this to my preferences?

Comment: I don't have an answer- but I want to know too. 30 day trending is not often to useful to me with a rapidly changing site. Most of the time I want to know what is going on today and maybe yesterday, but that's it.

Comment: https://somethingididnotknow.wordpress.com/2013/06/21/change-default-date-range-in-google-analytics/ This might still work, give it a go if you are brave enough ;)

Comment: Apparently he published it as a Chrome extension also in same article. The link for it is https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1787223/analyticsApp.crx.zip